# Avoiding conversion warning in Fortran array of non-default kind

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have the following command to set my array

```
Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
Integer (Int8), Allocatable :: iu(:)

Allocate (iu(4))
iu = [4,3,2,1]
```

How can I stop the compiler giving me

```
Allocate (iu(4));  iu = [4,3,2,1]
                       1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion 
from INTEGER(4) to INTEGER(1) at (1) [-Wconversion]
```

Comment: you should show the declaration of `Int8` to improve the question quality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[High Performance Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30128365) about solves your problem.  However, assuming `int8` isn't the default kind (which the error messages supports) each element in the array constructor given in that answer should have the same type (they have) and kind (they haven't) parameter.  So:

```
iu = [4_int8,3_int8,2_int8,1_int8]
```

is a valid constructor which shouldn't involve conversion.

It's a bit tedious to do that, especially with many elements, so it's worth noting that (as described in Fortran 2008 4.8) it's possible to use a type specification in the array constructor to specify the type and type parameters of the array.  You can, then, write

```
iu = [integer(Int8) :: 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

where the values need now only be conformable with `integer(Int8)`.

Whether gfortran complains about conversion seems to depend on the compiler version.  Testing with an old version there was still a warning, with 4.9.0 there wasn't.

Comment: Yes, bit is tedious, but that's the way to fix it.

Comment: Is is similar when using character arrays and the elements are of different lengths.

Comment: The two type-specifications are indeed closely related (see F2008 4.8).  In this answer it's kind type parameters, with the characters you mention it's length type parameters (also), that must match.  However, I've no idea the implications then on conversion and warning.

Comment: I shall try it and report back.

Comment: I confirm that `iu = [integer(Int8) :: 4, 3, 2, 1]` does not report a warning while looking neater than  `iu = [4_int8,3_int8,2_int8,1_int8]`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
iu = [4_int8,3,2,1]
```

But it is just a warning and the other way to stop the compiler would be to set or unset a flag.  Since you're silent on which compiler you're using I won't guess what's in its documentation or what flag to set to what value.

Comment: Isn't that illegal: different kind parameters in the same constructor? [Assuming `int8` doesn't correspond to default kind.]

Comment: I don't think so, but I didn't try it, I'm working on a machine without a Fortran compiler.   I have some dim memory of the kind being taken from the first element when you initialise an array that way.  And I'm about to go home so will check in later to see how much rep my rash guess has cost me.

Comment: I do not want to get the warning when the flag is set. I am using `gcc-5.0`

Comment: If you don't want to get a particular warning you have two choices: either avoid the condition that causes the compiler to raise the warning, or tell the compiler to be quiet.  It's up to you which one you choose.

Comment: I shall use the `_int8` declaration.