# Type error when compiling a real valued array. Fortran error #7113

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I have written the following function to take in six real valued parameters and return a 1D array.

```
FUNCTION G(a, b, c, d, e, f)

    IMPLICIT NONE

    ! SPECIFICATION SECTION
    REAL,                 INTENT(IN)  :: a
    REAL,                 INTENT(IN)  :: b
    REAL,                 INTENT(IN)  :: c

    REAL,                 INTENT(IN)  :: d
    REAL,                 INTENT(IN)  :: e
    REAL,                 INTENT(IN)  :: f

    REAL, DIMENSION(1:3)              :: G
    REAL, DIMENSION(3,3)              :: T       
    REAL, DIMENSION(1:3)              :: H

    ! EXECUTION SECTION
    T = RESHAPE( (/1, 0, -sin(b), &
                   0, cos(a), sin(a)*cos(b), &
                   0, -sin(a), cos(a)*cos(b)/), &
                   (/3,3/) )
    H = (/d, e, f/)
    G = someOtherUnimportantFunction(H,T)

    ! SUBPROGRAM SECTION

END FUNCTION G
```

This function does not compile and results in the error on the line with the RESHAPE function call:

```
error #7113: Each ac-value expression in an array-constructor must have the same type and type parameters.   [COS]
```

This error repeats for a total of 5 errors with the above text, except the final 4 do not have the `[COS]` on the end. This error seems to suggest that the 1s and 0s are being interpreted as different types than the trig functions, and, indeed, if I change the 1s to 1.0s and the 0s to 0.0s, the function compiles correctly. This is confusing to be however, as I have many similar functions above this one that have similar `RESHAPE` calls with both integer type expressions of 1s and 0s in addition to sines and cosines of angles. Those `RESHAPE` function calls compile just fine. Why is this RESHAPE call any different?

It is my understanding that previous `RESHAPE` commands were implicitly type converting the integers to REAL valued variables. Why is this type conversion not happening now?

Example of a correctly compiling RESHAPE call with mixed integer and REAL data types:

```
U = RESHAPE( (/cos(j), 0,  sin(j), 0, 1, 0, -sin(j), 0, cos(j)/),(/3, 3/) )
```

U is a REAL 3x3 array and j is a REAL valued angle.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30128290) is related, but there's surely a better duplicate target.

Comment: I went back and looked more closely at the previous calls to RESHAPE. all the arrays I passed to it contained multiple elements of the forms  `[integer value of 0 or 1]` and `[trigFunction(angle)]`. However, only the RESHAPE call in question _began_ with an integer. The rest began with trig functions. Thus, I did not pass arrays of all one type or the other. Does the first element type matter for type conversion of the rest of the entries?

Comment: All elements in the constructor must be of the same type and kind, unless `[real::...]` syntax is used.  What the first element is is irrelevant (although a compiler may not complain some ways)

Comment: If both U and T are declared as real valued 3x3 arrays, the first element doesn't matter so long as it can be implicitly type converted, and both contain `0` and `1` as array entries in addition to `sin(angle)` and `cos(angle)`, why did U type convert the `1` and `0` from INTEGER to REAL while T causes a type error?

Comment: There **NO** implicit conversion taking place here. All elements must be of the same type. That's what everyone tells you, but you don't listen. You can set the type explicitly as @francescalus showed above.

Comment: I have been "listening" with all my ability to your comments and those of High Performance Mark and fracescalus. I hear all of you loud and clear when you say that all elements in the constructor must be of the same type. However, I remain confused because _the U array has elements of both type INTEGER and type REAL in its constructor_ **and it compiles without error**. Since U is specified to be of type REAL, there are integers in its constructor in addition to REAL valued trig functions, and it compiles,  I see no way that implicit type conversion is not occurring! (the integers 1 and 0 ...

Comment: are being implicitly type converted to REAL type values). Simply telling me that T does not compile because all elements must be of the same type does not answer my question because of the array U's successful compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From some experiments, it seems that the behavior of `reshape` (or more precisely, a temporary array created inside the `reshape` function) observed above is vendor extensions for some particular version of compiler (maybe ifort14?). Please compare the results for `B` and `C` below, which depend on the compilers and versions used.

```
! [compilers used]
! ifort 14 and 16 (both with an option '-standard-semantics')
! gfortran 4.8 and 7.1
! Oracle studio fortran 12.5
! PGI Fortran Community Edition 2017.4

program main
    implicit none
    real :: A( 3 ), B( 3 ), C( 3 )

    !-------------------------
    ! RHS = uniform integer array

    A = [ 1, 2, 3 ]    !! an integer temporary array is created for RHS and assigned to A (with integer -> real conversion)
    print *, [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    print *, "A = ", A

    ! gfortran: PASS
    ! ifort16 : PASS
    ! ifort14 : PASS
    ! oracle  : PASS
    ! pgi     : PASS

    !-------------------------
    ! RHS = [ real, integer, integer ]

    B = [ 1.1, 2, 3 ]
    print *, [ 1.1, 2, 3 ]
    print *, "B = ", B

    ! gfortran: Error: Element in REAL(4) array constructor at (1) is INTEGER(4)
    ! ifort16 : Error: If type specification is omitted, each element
    !                  in an array-constructor must have the same type
    !                  and kind type parameters. 
    ! ifort14 : PASS (*)
    ! oracle  : Error: All ac-value expressions in an array constructor
    !                  must have the same type and type parameters.
    ! pgi     : PASS (*)

    !-------------------------
    ! RHS = [ integer, real, integer ]

    C = [ 1, 2.2, 3 ]
    print *, [ 1, 2.2, 3 ]
    print *, "C = ", C

    ! gfortran: Error: Element in INTEGER(4) array constructor at (1) is REAL(4)
    ! ifort16 : Error: (same message as for B)
    ! ifort14 : Error: Each ac-value expression in an array-constructor
    !                  must have the same type and type parameters.
    ! oracle  : Error: (same message as for B)
    ! pgi     : PASS (**)

    ! The error message from ifort-14 is the same as that shown in the question.

end
```

Results:

```
!-------------------------
gfortran, ifort-16, oracle

      1         2         3
 A =  1.000000  2.000000  3.000000

 ! B and C => error

!-------------------------
ifort-14

      1         2         3
 A =  1.000000  2.000000  3.000000

      1.100000  2.000000  3.000000   (*)
 B =  1.100000  2.000000  3.000000   (*)

 ! C => error

!-------------------------
PGI
      1         2         3
 A =  1.000000  2.000000  3.000000    

      1.100000  2.000000  3.000000    
 B =  1.100000  2.000000  3.000000    

      1         2         3           (**)
 C =  1.000000  2.000000  3.000000    (**)
```

So it is probably more portable not to mix elements of different types in an array constructor (even if some compilers allow it...).

On the other hand, if we specify the (uniform) element type of an array constructor as `[ real :: ... ]` (as suggested in the comments), we can mix elements of different types, e.g.:

```
B = [ real :: 1.1, 2, 3 ]
print *, [ real :: 1.1, 2, 3 ]
print *, "B = ", B

C = [ real :: 1, 2.2, 3 ]
print *, [ real :: 1, 2.2, 3 ]
print *, "C = ", C
```

which gives (for all the compilers above):

```
      1.100000  2.000000  3.000000
 B =  1.100000  2.000000  3.000000

      1.000000  2.200000  3.000000
 C =  1.000000  2.200000  3.000000
```

(*) This pattern seems just permissive and of little harm because `integer` is converted to `real`.

(**) But I think this pattern may be problematic (depending on cases) because `real` is implicitly "down-converted" to `integer` (which may not be the intent of the programmer...)

Comment: Though I guess the standard behavior in Fortran is to determine the uniform element type of an array constructor from the first element, I don't know where it is written in the Standards document ... (so please check by yourself XD)

Comment: It does not have to be written there. The elements must all be of the same type, so it does not matter if you first look at the first element or the last element.

Comment: Thanks for your info. It seems reasonable that if the element type is uniform, then the choice of the first or last element etc does not matter for type determination. (But then, gfortran's error message also seems somewhat misleading...) I have deleted the "first element" thing from the answer (and added a link to a Docs page).

Comment: @roygvib, You demonstrated the exact behavior of various compilers that I was looking for. I have since confirmed that my compiler, ifort 2011, has all the same results as its successor ifort 14 that you demonstrated. I will keep this information in mind as I continue my work. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @roygvib any idea why I get the same error when compiling? REAL,PARAMETER,DIMENSION(n) :: a_be=(/211,237,0.1/)

Comment: @HermanToothrot I think it's because the array on the right-hand side contains two integers and a real number in a mixed manner. So we need to write it as  `REAL,PARAMETER :: a_be(*) = (/ 211.0, 237.0, 0.1 /)`  or using a square bracket as `real, parameter :: a_be(*) = [ 211.0, 237.0, 0.1 ]` (where the array size is automatically determined by writing it as `a_be(*)` ) Another method is to specify `real` in the array literal, such that `real, parameter :: a_be(*) = [ real :: 211, 237, 0.1 ]` (In this case, mixing integer and reals are OK... I think these points are pretty confusing.)

Comment: @roygvib thank you for the response, very counter-intuitive!